# Remove stale data from exporting endpoint

Tags: prometheus

We've noticed huge CPU and RAM usage by our Prometheus instance and are looking into ways of lowering this.

Some of the data we expose has an `ApplicationVersion` label attached to it. Each time we release a new version (which happens a few times/week), every metric will basically be duplicated because of this. Once all servers have this new version and we don't rollback, this `ApplicationVersion` should never occur again.

Is it sensible to have a cleanup job in our exporter to remove this data?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a label like ApplicationVersion to your data is considered an anti-pattern, for some of the reasons you've discovered.

https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus/ describes the recommended approach.

Comment: I read through that post but I'm not quire sure yet how this works. How does `prometheus_build_info{job="prometheus",version="1.0.1"}` connect to `prometheus_local_storage_memory_series{job="prometheus"}`? Surely the latter must somehow store its version as well?

Comment: I believe this might not apply to my scenario since the `ApplicationVersion` is a property of messages we send on a rabbitqueue. This rabbit queue is then read from by prometheus -- there's no host to pass labels from.

Comment: In that case you may wish to not expose the ApplicationVersion at all.

Comment: That, sadly, is not an option since one of the main reasons we're adopting prometheus is keeping track of how new releases affect us. Knowing that -- does it make sense to remove that data from our output?